# jquery post to php not working in windows 10

Tags: php, jquery

jquery `$.post` to PHP not working on new windows 10 machine. Online hosting provider everything works fine although upon downloading website to new windows 10 machine post php 5.6 setup does not to load the php page being called via jquery. Don't know what else to check, frazzled to say the least; hoping for some feedback. thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
post_data = {'first_name'    : $('input[name=ifirstname]').val(),
             'last_name'     : $('input[name=ilastname]').val(),
             'user_email'    : $('input[name=iemail]').val(),
             'phone_number'  : $('input[name=iphone]').val(),
             'subject'       : $("#srequest :selected").text(),
             'msg'           : $('[name=tmessage]').val()
             };
         $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){
             if(response.type == 'error'){
                 output = response.text;
                 alert(output);
             }else{
                 output = response.text;
                 alert(output);
                 setDefaultVals();
             }
         }, 'json');
```

Comment: Well, do you have a local server installed, i.e. an environment that can run PHP, or are you just accessing files via the `file:///` protocol?

Comment: Open your browser console and see what errors you see

Comment: First, you have to be sure you have a working server on your Windows 10. I'm talking about Apache or Nginx. Then you must also have PHP installed on the machine. On Windows there are is a famous packaged LAMP distribution called Xampp. I suggest you trying that.

Comment: IIS10 '<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>' Compiler  MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)     Loaded Configuration File  C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.ini

Comment: console from debugger:  Content-Length485Content-Typetext/htmlDateTue, 28 Mar 2017 11:21:22 GMTServerMicrosoft-IIS/10.0X-Powered-ByPHP/5.3.28
Acceptapplication/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01Accept-Encodinggzip, deflateAccept-Languageen-US,en;q=0.5Connectionkeep-aliveContent-Length230Content-Typeapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8Cookiesc_is_visitor_unique=rx10670425.1490700058.55E5B6596A334F1C6FCB7762BE93250C.9.6.6.6.6.5.1.1.1HostlocalhostRefererhttp://localhost/User-AgentMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0X-Requested-WithXMLHttpRequest

Comment: i should also mention that i installed php manager to test every version of PHP with no success. Any other feedback would be greatly appreciated. thanks.